# Cascading Generic Type declarations in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, nested-generics

I am having a hard time finding this anywhere if this is a common problem but I am dealing with what is essentially a cascading type problem.

```
public class Graph<E> {

    private LinkedList<Node<E>> nodes;

    public Graph() {
        this.nodes = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public E[] getNodes() {
        ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node<E> node : nodes)
            list.add(node.getObject());
        return list.toArray(new E[0]); // any way to make this line work?
    }

    // other important stuff
}
```

I want to do something like this, however I can't instantiate the generic array this way. Where the getNodes() returns the content of the Nodes, not the Nodes themselves, but I can't figure out how.

I was thinking that the Node generic being defined by the Graph generic would mean that the Node class always has the same type as the Graph class. Is that not the case?

The Node class looks like

```
public class Node<E> {

    private LinkedList<Edge> edges;
    private E obj;

    public E getObject() {
        return obj;
    }

    // other useful stuff
}
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: all that is needed now is to make the returned Array of the right type. Is there a way to get an Array from an ArrayList that has a generic type assignment?

Comment: If it were possible, don't you think `ArrayList` would have done it?

Comment: This is a generic version of the problem that I am having. Right now there is no point in creating the Custom class because it adds no new functionality but my actual code does. As far as I can tell, I can't find a way around needing this type of implementation.

Comment: Just do what `ArrayList` does: `public <T> T[] getThings(T[] a) { return things.toArray(a); }`

Comment: Alternatively: `public E[] getThings(IntFunction<E[]> generator) { return things.toArray(generator.apply(things.size())); }`. You can call it like this: `customClass.getThings(GenericType[]::new)`

Comment: what is the `IntFunction<E[]>`?

Comment: It's a functional interface that accepts the array size and produces a new array.

Comment: actually let me just edit the question to reflect the actual problem because it is a bit more complex than this.

Comment: *FYI:* Your `for` loop should use `Node<E>`, not the *raw* `Node`.

Comment: ok great, that makes the problem simplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else came up with an answer that did not work but gave me an idea that ended up working, but they also put it in the comments section of the question so I will  reiterate here and answer my own question.

This code works to solve the problem. I more or less lifted the logic from the ArrayList source code for their `toArray(E[] a)` function (with some of the meat of it cut out of course).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E[] getNodes(E[] a) {
    int size = nodes.size();
    // creates an empty array of the right size and type
    E[] arr =(E[]) java.lang.reflect.Array
            .newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    // fills that array with the correct data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = nodes.get(i).getObject();
    return arr;
}
```

Look at the ArrayList source code in order to see some logic that goes a step farther and accomplishes the same task in a way that is also Thread safe.

Comment: if you don't use the passed array, just use `Class<E>` as parameter. Works almost the same, but doesnt need to create new array when accessing it. E.class will do.

Answer (score 1):

You need some form of reification of E in your `getThings` method.

If you want to keep the signature of `getThings` as it is, you can add a construtor parameter to provide the actual class `E`. With that class you can create an array to pass to the `toArray(E[])` method of `List<E>`

```
private final Class<E> type;
private final List<E> list;

public CustomClass(Class<E> type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E[] getThings() {
    Object[] reference = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(type, list.size());
    return (E[]) list.toArray(reference);
}
```

Comment: sorry I changed the question to a different example because I thought the answer might need more info, but that might actually work. Just wondering though, how does the `Class<E> type` work exactly?

Comment: You can also move the `Class<E> type` parameter down to the `getThings()` method.

Comment: is it possible to use the `Class<E>` type to assign the `Array` a type?

Comment: @user3785637 what do you mean with "assign the Array a type"?